# Storing html content in wordpress database using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I've made a wordpress plugin, in which I have a few div's.
I'm trying to get the content of the div with the code below.

```
var arhive = j( "div.page2" ).html();
                    console.log(arhive);
```

Works fine, the problem is when I'm trying to send it to the server to update the database with the new content.

```
j.ajax({
    url: "send_data.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {html: arhive} ,
    success: function (response) {
       // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

This is the content of my send_data.php file.

```
$var = $_POST["html"];



$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => 4137,
      'post_content' => '$var',
  );

// Update the post into the database
wp_update_post( $my_post);
echo "success";
```

I don't know why but I get 500 error, and the data doesn't get stored, any ideas what may cause this?

[image: This is the error I get]

Comment: What problem? Have you tried first encode `archive`? Have you tried sending it properly formatted like `data: {html: archive}`?

Comment: Hello, no , I think I managed to work this step, my problem might be on the php side. Working on it.

Comment: comment above should help you send the html code properly formatted into a variable "html". On the PHP you can access the data using $_POST["html"]. And to store it into the database you can check this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: hey there alex why do you need the html in the backend why not send only data?

Comment: where is your backend code??

Comment: I've writen this plugin in a rush, it's made using jqueryUI, you can basically drag and drop li's from a panel to another and arange them, when you click save buton, it will save the div's content, the li's in the order you set.

Comment: Instead of storing the HTML in a particular order, why not have a key/value map with a unique ID for each `li` and a sort order field. Order by the sort order when retrieving and then output the ordered items.

Comment: You can't write to a database using javascript (excluding node.js). If you want to use php to do this then this has nothing to do with Javascript, ajax, etc. You need to actually learn some php and I'd imagine SQL, etc. Basically this is far too broad a question

Comment: I'm using php and mysql, I'm working on the php file, but I found what I was looking for. In the first 2 comments.

Comment: Still not working guys, i've edited the question with more infos. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a wordpress action to handle the AJAX call and then use the data to store them into the database:

**Wordpress action inside your plugin that stores the posted data**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_plugin_ajax_store', 'my_plugin_ajax_store_callback' );

function my_plugin_ajax_store_callback() {
    $whatever_data = $_POST['whatever'];

    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database
    $wpdb->insert("wp_plugin_table", array(
        "whatever" => $whatever_data,
    ));

    echo 'Stored: '.$whatever_data;

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

**And you can setup the ajax call like this**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        'action': 'my_plugin_ajax_store',
        'whatever': 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

For more information on wordpress ajax calls, see here [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).